# vue-router : how to remove underline from router-link

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, routerlink

This results in an underlined link:

```
<li><router-link to="/hello">Hello</router-link></li>
```

My understanding is that the `router-link` element generates an `a` tag.

I've tried these things in the CSS:

```
router-link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

```
router-link a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

```
router-link a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

..but unfortunately none of these work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vue component tags don't generate HTML tags.
Look in the DOM inspector to see what HTML tags actually exist.

You need to use regular classnames.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. The `router-link` turns into an `a`. `li a { }` in CSS seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

If anyone using Vuetify comes across this question, note that the styling below do not work due to Vuetify's in built styles. You must instead use inline CSS styling:

```
<router-link
 style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;"
 to="/hello">
```

Answer (score 29):

It is Converted into `<a ...`
So to remove the underline try this

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: This one worked for me. Thank you.
I added a script to the vue.

Answer (score 23):

You can try targeting the list item link like this:

```
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the tag prop of router link to use the li css class like this:

```
<li><router-link tag="li" to="/hello">Hello</router-link></li>
```

The link will now use li css propertys but still work as like a normal router link.

Answer (score 9):

Add a class to router-link tag:

```
<router-link class="routerLink" to="/hello">Hello</router-link>
```

Then give css to the class:

```
.routerLink{
     text-decoration: none;
 }
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 2):

### **SCSS**

```
div /deep/ .v-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

### **CSS**

```
div >>> .v-list a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: /deep/ is deprecated `[Deprecation] /deep/ combinator is no longer supported in CSS dynamic profile.`

Answer (score 2):

Even in React-Router. The Link tag makes the text underlined. Because any text (h1, h3, p) inside  tag are converted to  anchor tags so:

```
a{text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer seems quite obvious.
I think my colleagues above forgot to mention that if you are using vuetify with the Laravel framework this problem can be solved as follows.
Access:

> resources\sass\app.scss file

And comment out the line:

> @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

This usually resolves this type of problem, which is actually a library conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Boostrap 5 you can use the class text-decoration-none

```
<router-link href="yourlink" class="text-decoration-none" >

</router-link>
```

see [bootsrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/) for reference. Just an additional information I am using Vue3 in my application